# android SU message popping up many times

Tags: android, root, reboot, su

I have a root application that I am trying to make. I have it so that the Launcher activity contains a ListView and when you press on an item it opens an AlertDialog and asks for confirmation. Its main feature is rebooting the device. I need to know how I can run "su" once on the startup and then when I click the other items it doesn't have to ask for su again

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SU manager application (like super su) installed in your device, you can disable prompting by selecting option "do not prompt" in the settings. But keep in mind, that you are allowing su command without prompting, it can be quite dangerous